# Retrieve single row and single column using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I know how to retrieve multiple columns or rows or both using the Hibernate method below. However am not sure how to retrieve only a single row or column and assign it to a String variable. Any help on this? Thanks

```
    Session session = getSessionFactory().beginSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

    sql.append("SELECT DISTINCT B.COLUMN_NAME ");
    sql.append("FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS A, ALL_CONS_COLUMNS B, ARCTBL C ");
    sql.append("WHERE A.TABLE_NAME = :TABLE_NAME AND A.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P' "); 
    sql.append("AND A.CONSTRAINT_NAME = B.CONSTRAINT_NAME ");
    sql.append("AND C.TABLENAME=A.TABLE_NAME AND A.TABLE_NAME=B.TABLE_NAME ");

    try{

    **listOfValues = session.createSQLQuery(sql.toString()).setParameter("TABLE_NAME", table).list();**
    //Change this to code below
String returnObjByHibernate = session.createSQLQuery(//Hibernate method)
    transaction.commit;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    //Logic here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a single row you must use uniqueResult() instead of list()

[http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29)

It returns a String or an array of Strings (I can't remember) so your line should be:

```
strValue = session.createSQLQuery(sql.toString()).setParameter("TABLE_NAME", table).uniqueResult();
```

Changing it to uniqueResult()[0] or uniqueResult().get(0) if the returned object is an 'array' or an 'Array'...

Answer (score 1):

Use `uniqueResult()` which returns object. And if there is multiple row matches the sql query then it throws `NonUniqueResultException`.

There is no option for  `uniqueResult()[0]` or `uniqueResult().get(0)`.

If your query returns multiple query you can use `list()`

If you are not sure how many rows are returned by the query but want a single value from one of them. Use `list().get(0)` or `list()[0]`

[see here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29)